# AppFabric Caching Services Non .NET Clients?

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

The question is basically summarized in the title: are there any non .NET clients for AppFabric Caching? The question comes because I think AppFabric Caching services are great but currently we are working on a design that would integrate a series of heterogeneous component and we might need to access Caching services from outside the .NET world.

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently replaced all usage of Appfabric with Redis on a very large project doing millions of transactions per day and one that uses alot of caching.

I find Redis a hundred times better than Appfabric and some of my reasons are:

- Setup of AppFabric is a pain (create user, make shared folder for appfabric.xml config)
- Changes to AppFabric and the cache client dll's SUCKED (converting from when it was called  velocity cache - probably of no impact to you, but once you've been through it you will know)
- AFAIK there are no non .net clients for Appfabric
- starting up the cache sometimes takes a few minutes and needs a kick in the butt to start working (all round painful)
- don't have to setup cache regions in the xml config etc (and manage on multiple deployments)

Just try out redis and use servicestacks redis client - you cannot go wrong!
redis is the best thing ever and will solve your cross platform/client issues too.

I cannot emphasize enough how much better redis is than appfabric - just try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will look more into Redis. Your answer would have been better if you just put the "AFAIK there are no non .net clients for Appfabric" first haha but really, thanks! =D

Comment: cool, i just mentioned some other things i hate about Appfabric to convince you to see the light and change to redis ;) I found that https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis is stable for running Redis on windows, and then as mentioned before http://www.servicestack.net/ for your .net client